# Measure child in GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm trying to override `measureChild` in `GridLayoutManager` to use specific layout params in measurement. But `GridLayoutManager` has its own private implementation of `measureChild`:

```
private void measureChild(View view, int otherDirParentSpecMode, boolean alreadyMeasured)
```

If I override public `measureChild` in `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`:

```
@Override
public void measureChild(View child, int widthUsed, int heightUsed) {
    super.measureChild(child, widthUsed, heightUsed);
}
```

It will be never called.

Is it possible to measure children in `GridLayoutManager`?

Answer (score 0):

The 2 methods have different signatures so you shouldn't have any problems overriding them. Depending on the parameters you specify for the function in your child class the appropriate super will be called.

However, you need to modify your child class that extends from GridLayoutManager to override all functions that use GridLayoutmanager's implementation of `measureChild` to be able use the other implementation.

To check which methods call `measureChild` inside GridLayoutManager you can look at the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.java)

**EDIT**: Seems like the `layoutChunk` method derived from LinearLayoutManager is package private so in this case I suppose the only way is to extend `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` and copy the entire code of GridLayoutManager replacing the `measureChild` calls with your own replacement modifying the code appropriately

Comment: It's not possible to override `GridLayoutManager`s `measureChild`, because it's a `private` method: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.java#L710

Comment: Perhaps I should have written it differently. What I mean is that as long as you modify the methods which use `measureChild` and replace them with your implementation it should work seamlessly.  In this case I believe it is just the `layoutChunk` method

Comment: @g4s8 it seems like manual implementation is the only way to go here. Check my edited answer though I would advise against it since it will be difficult to maintain the code against future updates of the library